# How can I get window.location.href in Elm?

Tags: elm, location-href

I have an `index.html` which contains my Elm app. The Elm app uses various `GET`s to an API served by the same server as the one that serves the `index.html`.

Rather than hardcode the URLs in my Elm code for the `GET`s, e.g.:

```
url =
    "http://localhost:8080/api/tasks"
```

is there a function which returns the value of `window.location.href`?

I'd like to do something like:

```
url =
    getHref() ++ "/api/tasks"
```

In this way, if I move my server to somewhere else I will not need to update all the urls in my Elm code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [elm-history](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/elm-history/latest/Location#location) package with the `location` function for this, but it's deprecated and doesn't exist for `0.18` version.

Then you might want to use [elm-navigation](https://github.com/elm-lang/navigation) package and explicitly store the current location in your model.

Please have a look at [this example](https://ellie-app.com/WWR44W8KpPa1). A program with navigation can be created via:

```
Navigation.program UrlChange
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = (\_ -> Sub.none)
    }
```

`UrlChange` here is a type of message, which triggers on every url change, so you can process it and set the current location:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UrlChange location ->
            ( { model | location = location }
            , Cmd.none
            )
```

And then *purely* get the `location.href` wherever the model is accessible.

In the provided application, this place is `view`: `viewLocation model.location`

In your application, it's, for example, something like this:

```
url model =
    model.location.href ++ "/api/tasks"
```

Comment: This answer is out of date now. The new module is elm/browser. The problem with *that* module is that it forces you to switch from Program to Browser, which is a much bigger change.

Answer (score 8):

Whilst the above answers your question, I think there is a more straightforward solution to the problem:

If the application code is being served from the same server (URL) as the API you want to access you don't need to specify the server - just the root relative path for your api i.e. you can make requests to `/api/tasks` from your elm code and the browser will sort out the rest for you.

This is how I addressed the problem in my deployed code.

Answer (score 4):

#### Use URL Builder to link to another page on your site

There's no need to specify the base url:

```
import Url.Builder exposing (absolute)
url = absolute [ "api", "tasks" ] []
-- results in "http://localhost:8080/api/tasks"
-- if working in your developer environment
-- the URL will automatically change in production
-- to the correct URL assuming you don't have any crazy set ups
```

And you definitely will not need to worry if your server URL changes. So you can easily switch from a development to production/staging environments without any additional configuration.