# Get host name of page from Elm

Tags: url, elm

I'm injecting a Elm feature to an existing page written by PHP.

The data responded from server for an item has `url : "this-is-detail-link.html"` and I need to get the host name to concat with the url.
For example:

```
case Msg of
    GoToDetailPage item ->
      let
        hostname = getHostNameFromElm // <- how can I get this?

        // expected: http://example.com/this-is-detail-link.html
        fullUrl = 
          Url.Builder.crossOrigin hostname item.url []

        cmd = 
          Browser.Navigation.load fullUrl


      in
      (model, cmd)
```

I am using `Browser.element`

```
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }
```

Try to search but not what I expect. It requires to use Browser.application, not a part like this. 
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get window.location.href in Elm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663630/how-can-i-get-window-location-href-in-elm)

Comment: Actually, that answer might be outdated.

Comment: If you're using `Browser.element` I suspect you'll need a port.

Comment: Ya! That's what I think right now. Using a port.

Comment: @bird Or you could pass it in as a flag.

Comment: @simplystuart, yes pass it through flag is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that you already solved it, but remember that you can always use Javascript through [ports](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/ports.html).

Here is an example app using ports to get the origin, please not that because Ellie renders inside an iFrame, I couldn't get the hostname directly. You just need to change to `window.location.hostname`.

https://ellie-app.com/8ggN625V8T6a1